# Defining automatic camera movements to static/fixed animation keyframes

Tags: arcgis-pro, animation, global-scene

I have over 50 keyframes in an animation of a Global Scene project. All these keyframes have the same camera look angle/distance but different overlayers. I would like to define a circular movement for all keyframes. I know that there are options such as "Circle Left Around Center" and "Circle Right Around Center" options under the Animation/Import tab, yet it creates four new keyframes as the motion. What I want is to be able to spread this circular motion to all 50+ keyframes. Is there a way to do that automatically rather than introducing new looks manually to each keyframe?